# Why is the Ui dialog title bar class not allowing me to query it?

Tags: jquery, dialog, phpstorm

Using PhpStorm and when I go to query the `ui-dialog-titlebar` in order to remove the title attribute it only gives me `ui-corner-all` or `ui-widget-content`. I have tried using different methods to grab the `ui-dialog-titlebar` selector. Here is my query

```
$(function() {
    dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
    });
    $(".btn-log").button().on("click", function(){
        dialog.dialog("open");
    })
});
```

Edit:  The code completion does not offer the ui-dialog-titlebar as a selector option.

Comment: Don't understand the question. How is PhpStorm preventing you from querying it? Is it just not offering it in code completion?

Comment: @Barmar yes the code completion does not offer the ui-dialog-titlebar